# Why is my LinkedHashMap merging key with value?

Tags: jenkins, groovy

**Intro**

I wrote some code for a Jenkins pipeline in Groovy that looks like this:

```
def sendNotifications (args) {
  // ... use args ...
  sendSlack(
    failOnError: true,
    color: '#00FF00',
    message: "foo",
    channel: "#mychan"
  )
}
// slackMessage not shown returns a string based on the args.
```

This code seemed to be working just fine in my pipeline. Now I want to test it. So I create a function that mocks out sendSlack because I don't want my test to send a Slack message, I want to check to see if the arguments passed to sendSlack are the expected ones. So I did this:

```
void testStubbedSendNotifications(Map inputArgs, ArrayList slackArgs) {
    def n = new Notifier()
    def sendSlackArgs = []
    n.metaClass.sendSlack = { Map x -> sendSlackArgs << x }
    n.sendNotifications(inputArgs)
    assert sendSlackArgs == slackArgs
}
```

What is happening here is simple. Instead of calling sendSlack, I'm pushing the arguments that would be called onto an ArrayList and then I check to make sure that list looks right in an assert. So this function takes arguments to call sendNotifications with as well as a list of expected values to see sendSlack being called with as a result.

**The Problem**

My expected values get mangled only in my tests. Instead of the arguments being a hash map like this:

```
[
  failOnError: true,
  color: '#00FF00',
  message: "foo",
  channel: "#mychan"
]
```

I instead get this:

```
[
  failOnError: true,
  color: '#00FF00',
  "message:foo" : null,
  channel: "#mychan"
]
```

Why does the message's key and value get merged into the key?

Comment: Are you sure a correct instance of `Map` is passed as one of the arguments? Also, you can just compare Maps instead of Lists.

Comment: The code is simplified but I am using a list here because my function can call sendSlack an arbitrary number of times. So I am checking for having the correct number of calls to the function and that each call has the right number of arguments.

What do you mean by "a correct instance of Map?"